# Was this question incorrectly closed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, closed-questions

[Here is a question about maintaining a personal ledger in an SQL database](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/133747/how-should-i-deal-with-the-fact-that-currencies-change-in-value-in-relation-to-e?noredirect=1#comment265201_133747). It seems to have been closed because it was about programming.

In my opinion, this is a valid question about personal bookkeeping, not programming. The core question is: which data should the asker "write down" in his ledger in order to account for changing exchange rates?

The fact that it's an SQL database is merely background information. The exact same question would also apply to a pen-and-paper ledger.

But the question is closed, and apparently, I'm "delusional" (see comments) for thinking this is an accounting question rather than a programming question.

Should this have been closed?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you could salvage the question by stripping out all the business about designing the DB. If the question really is about managing your finances it shouldn't be necessary to ask your question. Your question really seems to be about data modeling and algorithms more than finance the way it is written.

If that is not your intent try removing all the extraneous bit about SQL tables and cursors.

Comment: Would the question be off-topic if the DB concepts were replaced by equivalent paper concepts? "I have ruled paper with these columns: timestamp_for_when_it_was_inserted_into_database
timestamp_for_when_the_transaction_happened
amount
currency_code
amount_in_EUR_when_it_happened..."

Comment: Probably. the question is a little unfocused.